# What is the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform reference used for?

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

Sorry for laic question, but I do not understand what the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform reference is for in a UWP application. This reference is added automatically. As I understand UWP is based on its own, separate api - the reference is **Universal Platform**. So the reference Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform should not be required. So my questions are thus:

1. What is Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform reference for?
2. Is this reference required to run a UWP application? If I remove the reference then application does not compile complaining about missing basic Object classes for example.

Comment: You would have seemed to have answered your own question

Answer (score 2):

This reference can be considered an alias for all the packages and references needed in a Universal Windows app.

Having a single entry keeps the list smaller and more manageable and avoids issues with references to incompatible versions of related files.

You need this entry. It is used to get all the files related to the version of UWP that you are targeting.

Comment: It is still unclear to me. So UWP does not use Universal Platform api directly but via .net core?

Comment: The .NET Core UWP package is for all of the .NET surface area (including object!). Things provided via WinRT (aka camera, XAML and other stuff) are provided via another mechanism.

Comment: this is the direction in which things are going to move. everything is going to ship as nuget packages. This allows us to ship updates at a faster cadence and hence new features as well as bug fixes without needing a new VS install or VS update.